# Cannot set the Security Context WARN 37240 --- [nio-9988-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound : No mapping for GET /swagger-ui/index.html

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, swagger, spring-boot-security

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    public static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";
    private static final String DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERN = "/api/.*";

    private ApiKey apiKeys() {
        return new ApiKey("JWT", AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "header");
    }

    private List<SecurityContext> securityContexts() {
        return Arrays.asList(SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(sf()).build());
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> sf() {

        AuthorizationScope scope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");

        return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("JWT", new AuthorizationScope[] { scope }));
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(getInfo()).securityContexts(securityContexts())
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKeys())).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();

    }

    private ApiInfo getInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo("Show management", "Show Management description of API.", "1.0", "Terms of service",
                new Contact("dev", "", ""), "License of API", "API license URL", Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

**Cannot set the Security Context **

code is a configuration class for Swagger in a Spring Boot application. It sets up Swagger to generate API documentation for the application's RESTful endpoints.

Let's go through the code and explain each part:

The SwaggerConfiguration class is annotated with @Configuration, indicating that it provides bean definitions.

The constant AUTHORIZATION_HEADER is defined as the name of the header used for authorization. It is set to "Authorization".

The constant DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERN is defined as the default include pattern for API paths. It is set to "/api/.*", which matches any path starting with "/api/".

The apiKeys() method creates an instance of ApiKey representing the JWT authentication scheme. It takes three arguments: the name of the scheme ("JWT"), the header name ("Authorization"), and the location of the header ("header").

The securityContexts() method creates a list of SecurityContext objects. In this case, it creates a single SecurityContext with the security references obtained from the sf() method.

The sf() method creates a list of SecurityReference objects representing the security references for JWT authentication. It creates a single SecurityReference with the scheme name ("JWT") and an array of AuthorizationScope objects. In this case, it sets the scope to "global" and the description to "accessEverything".

The api() method is annotated with @Bean and creates a Docket object. The Docket is the main Swagger configuration class. It is configured with the apiInfo(), securityContexts(), and securitySchemes() methods.

The apiInfo() method creates an ApiInfo object representing the metadata for the API documentation. It includes details such as the title, description, version, terms of service, contact information, license, and license URL.

The select() method is called on the Docket object to specify the APIs that should be included in the documentation. In this case, RequestHandlerSelectors.any() is used to include all request handler methods.

The paths() method is called on the Docket object to specify the paths that should be included in the documentation. In this case, PathSelectors.any() is used to include all paths.

The build() method is called on the Docket object to build the final Docket instance.